# Accessing a Webservice Apex Method via SOAP-UI

Tags: soap-api, webservices, apex-webservice

So I have created a simple webservice apex class that follows the second example for webservice on this link:

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services_and_Callouts#Apex_Web_Services

```
global class MyWebService_DUMMY {
webservice static String makeContact(String contactLastName) {
    contactLastName = 'testing';
    return contactLastName;
    }
}
```

I then generated the class' WSDL and added it to SOAP-UI tool just so I could look on how to access it. I assume that I just need to supply the Username and Password in the request but looking at the WSDL, I can't find any tag for Username and Password.

How do you supply the Username and Password in order to access the Apex webservice above?

I did found a tag for 'sessionId' in the Header part of the WSDL but I also don't know what to do on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to generate one additional Enterprise or Partner WSDL to make login request. There you will supply your credentials and will get security token in response.
[image]

Next you will use that response and will make request.

Comment: Oh I see. so does this mean that the third party must first connect via Partner WSDL before connecting to the Apex Webservice class? Ok will see check this one out in SOAP-UI.

Comment: yes they need to get the token first and they can use our custom we service.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I just tested in SOAP-UI and I was definitely able to access the dummy webservice class. What I did was first requested the sessionID via Partner WSDL username and password Request then once I got the sessionID, I then used this on the WSDL generated for the APEX Class and it worked! Again thank you so much!